# How to write XPath for the text present outside the tags?

Tags: c#, xpath

```
<div class="accordion_browse">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.silverpages.sg/tools/e-care-locator" 
   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <span class="browse_img">
        <img src="/sites/assets/assets/directory/icons/eldercare.png"/>
    </span>
    Eldercare Services
    <i class="indicator fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note: the text required is 'Eldercare Services'

Code:

```
string Eldercare = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')")).Text; 
Console.WriteLine(Eldercare + " found");
Assert.IsTrue(Eldercare.Contains("Elder"), Eldercare + " not found");
```

Comment: Is this for a test using Selenium or is it a web crawler app? Also can you provide a link to the site you have taken this HTML from.

Comment: Yes, it is required for 'Selenium automation'.

Comment: Show how you tried to solve your problem

Comment: string Eldercare = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')")).Text;
Console.WriteLine(Eldercare + " found");                                                            Assert.IsTrue(Eldercare.Contains("Elder"), Eldercare + " not found");

Comment: Can you describe your problem and what exactly you want your script to do as for not is not quite clear? Note that in your XPath there is no closing square bracket

Comment: https://www.healthhub.sg/directory/blood-banks                                                           The above is the link. Can you please help me to get the Xpath for 'Eldercare Services' which is listed in the left pane.

Comment: XPath that returns text node is not permitted in Selenium

Answer (score 0):

A text node is retrieved using the text node `text()`

XPath: `"/body/div/text()"`

That will retrieve all children text nodes of `/body/div`.

`"/body/div/text()[1]"` will retrieve the first text node inside `/body/div`

Additional Reading on XPath:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

The given xpath is looking good, but `By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')")` example code missing a closing square bracket: `By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')]")`

With this fix, the xpath will give the `a` element

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.silverpages.sg/tools/e:care:locator" aria:expanded="false" aria:controls="collapseExample">
<span class="browse_img">
 <img src="/sites/assets/assets/directory/icons/eldercare.png"/>
</span>
Eldercare Services longtext
<i class="indicator fa fa:chevron:right pull:right" aria:hidden="true"/>
</a>
```

**The missing bracket should fix the code.**

If Selenium would have work with text elements it could be

```
//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')]/text()
```

results would be a string array with 3 strings. the middle one has the expected string, because before the span and after i elements there will probably be two empty strings.

```
Text = 

Text = 
    Eldercare Services longtext

Text =
```

If use a second filter for the text, it would result the expected string only

//a[contains(.,'Eldercare Services')]/text()[contains(.,'Elder')]